Vuetify: How to position navigation bar in relation to app bar
I recently upgraded Vuetify to the latest version.  I was previously using 3.5.17, and am now using 3.6.6.  I'm seeing an issue with the navigation drawer in relation to the app bar.  Previously, the navigation drawer extended all the way to the top of the window, covering the app bar.  This is the desired appearance.  Now, however, in 3.6.6, the app bar takes precedence and covers the navigation drawer.  Nothing has changed in my layout code.  How can I get back the previous behavior, with the navigation drawer covering the app bar?

I discovered that Vuetify 3.6.0 introduced an order prop on the navigation bar and app bar.  This value is 0 by default.  To have the navigation bar take precendence over the app bar, set the order prop on the app bar to a higher value than the navigation bar.  Higher precedence is given to lower values.
